# Всем, привет. Помогите остановить функцию, если это возможно

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа, setinterval

Пытаюсь написать примитивную игру в "кости" Есть массив с ссылками на .png , есть функция которая перебирает этот массив, и кнопка которая запускает перебор. И есть метод планирования setInterval который имитирует быстрый перебор изображений.

```
function start() {
    image.src = imags[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags.length)];
    image2.src = imags2[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags2.length)];

    setInterval(start, 100);
}

document.querySelector('.buttonStart').addEventListener('click', start);
```

Вопрос , как теперь остановить эту функцию. Если , конечно, такая конструкция вообще допустима. За любой отклик , заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let timer;
function start() {
  image.src = imags[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags.length)];
  image2.src = imags2[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags2.length)];
}

document.querySelector('.buttonStart').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = setInterval(start, 100);
});
document.querySelector('.buttonStop').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let isOdd = false;
let interval;

startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    dice.style.setProperty(isOdd ? '--bg-x' : '--bg-y', number);
    isOdd = !isOdd;
  }, 400);
});

stopButton.addEventListener('click', () => clearInterval(interval));
```

```css
#dice {
  --bg-x: 0;
  --bg-y: 0;
  --size: 100px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  transition: background-position 150ms;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iSCZ.png);
  background-position: calc(var(--bg-x) * var(--size)) calc(var(--bg-y) * var(--size));
}
```

```html
<div id="dice"></div>
<button id="startButton">start</button>
<button id="stopButton">stop</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Задача была в следующем: Не приклеивать вторую кнопку, а имея одну кнопку - запускать функцию, которая перебирает массив в течении некоторого времени  и сама останавливается, показывая результат. Решение вижу следующее:

```
 function list() {
    image.src = imags[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags.length)];
    image2.src = imags2[Math.floor(Math.random() * imags2.length)];
}

function start() {
    count = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        count++;
        if (count == 30) {
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        list();
    }, 100);
}


document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', start);
```

В таком варианте всё задуманное, работает как надо =)
Поправьте если накосячил, всем откликнувшимся низкий поклон =)